# How to track User location until he reaches a specific place?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, maps

I'm new to Mobile apps development.

let's assume i have an office with some employees.

i want to check-in employees by checking their location
.
if their location = office location then they are in.
if their location =! office location then they are out.

How can i Achieve that ?

Comment: to Get location you have to use 
Network location Or GPS location
network location is not fine location (about 300 m  or more)
Gps location .. Is not work fine Indoors

Answer (score 0):

Use Geofence to track user enter/exit/dwell(stays there for some time).Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement geofence concept... just set geofence at your office with radius than you can easily track their in and out activity..

Take a look at this documentation... this may help you to implement geofence...
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Just sent silent push notifications when particular user enters or goes outside the geofence...